# What is the implicit domain of an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, functions, improper-integrals

The derivative of $f(x) = \ln(x)$ is $\frac{1}{x}$, with domain $(0, \infty)$.  The derivative implicitly has the domain of $f(x)$.

Reversing the direction, the indefinite integral / antiderivative

$$
 \int \frac{1}{x}\,dx
$$

is [solved by Khan](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/ap-calculus-ab/ab-integration-new/ab-6-8b/v/antiderivative-of-x-1?modal=1) with the answer $\ln(|x|) + C$ where $x \ne 0$.  As opposed to the naive answer $\ln(x)$ which would have to be limited to $x > 0$.

I was wondering whether we should implicitly assume indefinite integrals are to be solved for the maximum possible domain? Any tips/corrections on how domains work with derivatives vs integrals is welcome.

Comment: Any operation that you apply on a function and yielding another function has the intersection of the domains of the input and the output as a domain. This applies to taking derivatives or primitives. For the derivative, the starting domain is small, you shouldn't get a bigger one in the end!

Comment: Thanks, Anthony.  If I understand correctly it's not about derivative vs integral, it's more about the function under consideration bottlenecking the domain

Comment: Yes. What's weird with your example is that the function log *extends* to a function log(|x|) which turns out to also work with the derivative. You could have extended log by the value 0 for negative x, but then taking derivatives this would be 0 for negative x (and this is a correct result), but it doesn't coincide with the 1/x you have. In general, everything is clear from the context.

Comment: One important thing to keep in mind is that there is more than one way of extending this beyond the original domain. Any function of the form $\log(x) + C_1$ when $x \gt 0$ and $\log(-x) + C_2$ when $x \lt 0$ with $C_1, C_2$ arbitrary constants is an antiderivative of $\frac{1}{x}$ over the domain $(-\infty, 0) \cup (0, \infty)$. When the domain is not connected, the Mean Value Theorem does not imply that a function with zero derivative everywhere must be constant. So $\log \left|x\right| + C$ is not the most general answer (it doesn't include cases where $C_1 \neq C_2$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not that the answer ${\ln(x) + c}$ is incorrect, as you pointed out it's just limited to ${x>0}$. When doing indefinite integrals, you should definitely be careful about specifying the domain over which your answer is correct. In this particular case, ${\ln|x| + c}$ is just an expression which encapsulates the integral for both cases ${x>0}$ and ${x<0}$

Comment: Is the more general result preferred?

Comment: @bgcode for sure yes, it's more compact. The notation ${\ln|x| + c}$ should just be interpreted as "to get the answer, we had to take the domain of the integral into consideration, and after doing so this is the most compact form to write the answer in"

Comment: The problem with this answer is that this is not the most general answer. See Tob Emack's comment to the original post for more details.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Answer (score 1):

The domain of an antiderivative function is trivially the subset of the domain of the integrand where it is *integrable*.

---

I would rather write a general indefinite integral of $\dfrac 1x$ as

$$\log(|x|)+C+C'u(x)$$ where $u$ denotes a Heaviside step.

Answer (score 0):

When we do mathematics outside a classroom setting, we must be careful. A function, to be uniquely defined, must have its domain specified. Otherwise, you are not actually talking about a function, but about a family of graphs. The symbol $\ln$ is a symbol which, by definition, refers to some function $(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R},$ and the domain is not changed unless otherwise specified. As such, we have the result that $$\forall{x\in(0,\infty)},\,\ln'(x)=\frac1{x}.$$ However, notice the following: if we define $\ln_-$ by $\ln_-:(-\infty,0)\rightarrow\mathbb{R},$ $\ln_-(x):=\ln(-x),$ then $$\forall{x\in(-\infty,0)},\,\ln_-'(x)=\frac1{x}.$$ As such, we can define a family of functions $f_{A,\,B}:(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R},$ with $$f_{A,\,B}(x)=\begin{cases}\ln_-(x)+A&x\lt0\\\ln(x)+B&x\gt0\end{cases}.$$ This family of functions satisfies the property that $$\forall{A,B\in\mathbb{R}},\,\forall{x\in(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)},\,f_{A,\,B}'(x)=\frac1{x}.$$ This to say, that if we define $g:(-\infty,0)\cup(0,\infty)\rightarrow\mathbb{R},$ $$g(x)=\frac1{x},$$ then we have that $$\forall{A,B\in\mathbb{R}},\,f_{A,\,B}'=g.$$ In conclusion: specifying your domain matters. A deduction as to what the antiderivatives or derivative is cannot be made without first talking about the domain.